# Can't use the dot button in the calculator application I'm making in <input type="number">

Tags: javascript, html, dom

so I'm making this calculator app using `<input type="number">` but when I try to type a dot clicking the html buttons I made it gives me this error: `The specified value "." is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+\.\d+|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?`
but if I click on the input and type dot using keyboard it works. Here's the code:

```
<input type="number" placeholder="Enter A Number....">

dot.addEventListener("click", function() {
    input.value += this.textContent;
})

<tr>
    <td><button id="dot">.</button></td>
    <td><button id="zero">0</button></td>
    <td><button id="equal">=</button></td>
</tr>
```

[image: Here's the calculator]

So that's the calculator.

Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: add the same validation function on events 'keyup keydown keypress change click'

Comment: @AbdelrahmanGobarah what validation function?

Comment: same of this `The specified value "." is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+\.\d+|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?`

Comment: @AbdelrahmanGobarah how can I do this, please if you have the answer type it in an answer so I can give you feedback

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the dot is actually not a number - it's a string. Your input textfield however is set to be of type '**number**'.

In the callback function for the click event you're trying to change the input field's value to the value of the **.textContent** property. This will always return a string thus you get an error.

I'd recommend storing all the inputs of your calculator's buttons inside a temporary string and ultimately do a **parseFloat()** on that variable before sending it to your input textfield. This will convert your input to a proper number.

e.g.

```
var myInput="";
dot.addEventListener("click", function() {
    myInput+=this.textContent;
    input.value = parseFloat(myInput);
})
```

Here's an example:

```js
var myInput = "";
dot.addEventListener("click", function() {
  myInput += this.textContent;
  input.value = parseFloat(myInput);
})
one.addEventListener("click", function() {
  myInput += this.textContent;
  input.value = parseFloat(myInput);
})
```

```html
<input type="number" id="input" placeholder="Enter A Number....">
<tr>
  <td><button id="dot">.</button></td>
  <td><button id="one">1</button></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying but it didn't work, it now gives me this in the console: `The specified value "NaN" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+\.\d+|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?` in addition to this: `The specified value "." is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+\.\d+|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?`

Comment: I've enhanced my answer with a working code snippet. Can you check it out and try to enter the number 1.1 and see if you're getting the same error again?

Comment: The code snippet does not work when I click on either button nothing happens and I tried copying the code into my app and still doesn't work, but anyway thanks for your effort

Comment: That's really strange. I've tested it successfully in Chrome and FireFox - what browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Chrome

Comment: Well, let's not get hung over this problem cause believe me I have more that's not done yet in that app and I don't know how to do yet or I tried doing something but didn't work at all, so I'm gonna ask another question and put the link in here, so it would be great if you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#Allowing_decimal_values), you can add a `step` attribute to the `input` tag to allow decimals. An example would be

```
<input type="number" step="0.01">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the I already can type a dot in the input using the keyboard, now I need to be able to type it using the button I made, I mean the button can't be just sitting there in the page doing nothing, don't get me wrong I tried your solution and now I can adjust the value using the up and down arrows on the keyboard, but that's not what I want. If you can think of something else that would be appreciated.